How to calculate $\int_0^t \frac{a(1+2x+2ax^2)}{(1+ax)^2} e^{-ax^2}\, dx$
I have given function: $f(x)= \frac{a(1+2x+2ax^2)}{(1+ax)^2} e^{-ax^2}; x>0; a>0.$ And I am supposed to calculate: $\int_0^t f(x)dx.$
I have tried solving this by substitution and product method, but nothing seems to be giving me the results.

It would be nice if you put your methods in the question by using latex.

$I=\int \frac{a(1+2x+2ax^2)}{(1+ax)^2}e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{dx}\\ 
I=-\int \left(-\frac{a}{(1+ax)^2}-\frac{2ax}{1+ax}\right)e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{dx}.$
Let $g(x)=\frac1{1+ax}$.
Now the integral becomes $
I=-\int (g'(x)+(-ax^2)'g(x))e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{dx}\\
I=-g(x)e^{-2ax^2}+C=-\frac{e^{-ax^2}}{1+ax}+C.$
